# How to rewrite a RewriteValve for Undertow / JBoss 7.2 EAP?

Tags: java, url-rewriting, jboss, jboss7.x, undertow

I'm migrating from JBoss 6.4.3 to JBoss 7.2 and saw a `Valves are no longer supported` warning during deployment. This came from a `jboss-web.xml` file with:

```xml
<valve>
    <class-name>org.jboss.web.rewrite.RewriteValve</class-name>
</valve>
```

...and a corresponding `rewrite.properties` file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} http
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Could anyone advise how to rewrite this (no pun intended) for Undertow?

Comment: This is not really a regex question. The rewrite rule just sends all http requests to https.

Comment: I've now replaced the regex tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a [`rewrite` filter](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.0/html/configuration_guide/configuring_the_web_server_undertow#undertow-configure-filters) in the Undertow subsystem, and then reference it in the server host within the configuration file (*standalone.xml* or *domain.xml* - depending on the mode in which you start the application server).

I can think of two options, which might help you:

1. Using the `JBoss Application Server Client` (should be placed in `path/to/jboss-7.2/bin/`)

   - Creating the rewrite filter with the custom name `redirect-http-to-https`:

   ```
   ./jboss-cli.sh --connect --command="/subsystem=undertow/configuration=filter/rewrite=redirect-http-to-https:add(redirect=\"true\",target=\"https://%{LOCAL_SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URL}\")"
   ```

   - Using/referencing the filter `redirect-http-to-https`:

   ```
   ./jboss-cli.sh --connect --command="/subsystem=undertow/server=default-server/host=default-host/filter-ref=redirect-http-to-https:add(predicate=\"equals(%p,80)\")"
   ```
2. Manually editing the respective config file (e.g. `standalone.xml`)

```html
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:11.0" default-server="default-server" [...]>
            <buffer-cache name="default"/>
    <server name="default-server">
        [...]
        <host name="default-host" alias="localhost">
            <filter-ref name="redirect-http-to-https" predicate="equals(%p,80)"/>
        </host>
    </server>
    [...]
    <filters>
        <rewrite name="redirect-http-to-https" target="https://%{LOCAL_SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URL}" redirect="true"/>
    </filters>
</subsystem>
```

Note: For the Undertow exchange attributes (e.g. `LOCAL_SERVER_NAME`) refer to [Undertow documentation](http://undertow.io/undertow-docs/undertow-docs-2.0.0/). Further, the part `predicate=\"equals(%p,80)\"` in the `filter-ref`checks the requested port (`%p` -> just another Undertow exchange attribute) and if it equals to `80`, then it triggers our redirect filter `redirect-http-to-https` - you can change the port `80` as per your need.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you know if there is a way of doing this in a jboss-web.xml file?

Comment: @SteveChambers Sorry, I never worked with `jboss-web.xml` before. If you have the possibility to use a reverse-proxy-server like Nginx, I would rather use it instead of reconfiguring the Undertow.

Comment: @SteveChambers My port is not getting changed (stays 8080) if I'm using any exchange attributes. It works without, for example: `target="https://localhost:8443/myapp"`. Any idea? I've tried multiple combinations, but one sample is `https://%{LOCAL_SERVER_NAME}:8443%{REQUEST_URL}`